# 504 timeout error occurs in wordpress whenever I use bulk Woocommerce's bulk action

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, woocommerce, timeout, connection-timeout

I operate an internet shopping malls through the Woocommerce plugin of Wordpress.
Unfortunately, whenever I conduct some action such as modification of product category or product delete through Woocommerce's bulk select function which exists Wordpress's manager page, 504 timeout error occurs.

Usually, when I select about 10 or more products and conduct some action, it does. I saw some answers and modified wp-config.php by adding two lines below.

`define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '1024M');`

`set_time_limit(300);`

How to fix this error and what can I do?

My boss is getting angry ...
Please help me...

Thank you for all your attention :)

Comment: Can you increase time limit above 3000

Comment: Yes, I can. I'll do that and keep you updated.

Comment: @vadivela Unfortunately, I did so but It doesn't work. In other words, there isn't any effects. Could you recommend another solutions?

Comment: How many products?

Comment: @vadivela Our site has about 5000 products and I select and command once a 20 products.